# Serializing Simple JSON String with Rails ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activeresource

I have a RESTful API call that acts like this:

```
HTTP GET http://addresss:port/settings/{setting}
```

which returns just the value of the setting specified as a simple string:

```
"settingValue"
```

I want to retrieve this value using a subclass of ActiveResource:Base

```
class Settings < ActiveResource:Base
  self.site = CONFIG['uri']
  self.collection_name = 'settings'
  self.format = :json
  ...
end
```

But when I call `Settings.find("Setting")`, I get `unexpected token at '"settingValue"'`.

I could change the format of the data returned from the API, but is there anyway  to get Rails to correctly handle this data?

Comment: Your api doesn't render json so Active Resource fails when it tries to parse a mere text/

Comment: isn't `"string"` legal JSON? It's being generate by GSON.

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com/ to check

Comment: Hm. I guess not. Is there any way to get it to serialize that simple string then?

Comment: don't use ActiveResource since you're not consuming a RESTful service,   use another means to communicate with apis like restclient

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api doesn't render json so Active Resource fails when it tries to parse a mere text.

Use another means to communicate with apis like [restclient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client/)